# ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid internet address newsapi.org)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have got runtime error "invalid internet address" but the api works fine .

Exception has occurred.
HttpException (HttpException: , uri = https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=d2c9e9553c4647f3add970ed74a812ee)

```
class News {
  List<ArticleModel> news = [];

  Future<void> getNews() async {
    String url;
    url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=d2c9e9553c4647f3add970ed74a812ee";

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (jsonData['status'] == "ok") {
      jsonData["articles"].forEach((element) {
        if (element['urlToImage'] != null && element['description'] != null) {
          ArticleModel articleModel = ArticleModel(
            title: element['title'],
            author: element['author'],
            description: element['description'],
            urlToImage: element['urlToImage'],
            //   publshedAt: DateTime.parse(element['publishedAt']),
            content: element["content"],
            url: element["url"],
          );
          news.add(articleModel);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try making it ``var url = Uri.parse("<your url>");``. Then do ``var res = await http.get(url);``

Comment: @darkstar What would that change?

Comment: See the GitHub issue relating to this error: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83792. It's not an issue with your implementation, it's a bug in Flutter.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore The ``Uri.parse()`` method gave me similiar errors when I first started using the http module. I switched it up and it worked‍♂️

Comment: @darkstar If you look at their code, you'll see they're also doing `Uri.parse`. Your proposal changes nothing. Please don't do voodoo programming.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore worked for me broski

Comment: @darkstar What did it work for? Just because you see "similar errors" does not mean the solution will work. It's not productive to throw out potential solutions if there is nothing that would indicate it would solve any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked for me after this change:

```
 Future<void> getNews() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=eg&apiKey=api');
    
   
    var response = await http.get(url);
```